# Unintentional vi mode in iTerm on Mac?

Tags: macos, command-line, vim, iterm2

I occasionally find that while working in iTerm the default Readline key bindings are replaced with the `vi` keybindings.

For example, I will try to go to the beginning of the line with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd>, and instead it will print the character `^A`, and then I won't be able to insert any text until I enter insert mode. I know this can be configured by setting the editing-mode in my inputrc file, but I don’t have that set in mine. Is there a way that I could be dynamically entering `vi` mode?

Comment: Could you have accidentally pressed Ctr+Alt+J  ? (This keycombo toggles between emacs-mode and vi-mode in many readline-compatible applications)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is related to the way the Mac OS X terminal handles terminal emulation and even color coding—which is related to control sequences—[as explained in this blog post](http://ricochen.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/mac-os-x-lion-terminal-color-remote-access-problem-fix/):

> After upgrading to Lion I noticed that the *Homebrew* theme that I’ve
>   been using since Snow Leopard doesn’t display colors correctly(using
>   different colors for directories, different types of files etc.) any
>   more when working on remote hosts via ssh (local dir colors still work
>   though) and switching to other themes doesn’t help. After messing
>   around with the Terminal settings I finally found the cause and a
>   solution. It seems Lion changed the terminal type to `xterm-color256`
>   during the upgrade (don’t remember what the setting was in SL though).
>   The solution is simple enough, just change the emulation type for
>   terminal from `xterm-color256` to `xterm-color` (see screenshot
>   below).

Fair warning, some of the advice in that comment thread is out of date since there no longer is a `xterm-color` in the terminal as of Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion). But I believe adjusting items in the “Advanced” tab (pictured) might help:

[image]

Comment: That's for the system-supplied Terminal, not iTerm. `xterm-256color` or `xterm-color` would be settings to use; I don't know of anything using the string `xterm-color256`. None of these color settings *should* have anything to do with changing the shell's editing mode (which doesn't necessarily mean that they *don't*).